# Start a setInterval timer only when needed ?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to move a div inside a div with arrow keys. However for it to work continuously, it needs a setInterval timer. I believe that because of this, browser has an unnecessary load. I want that the timer only works when an arrow key is '**kept**' pressed and not otherwise.

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed);
window.addEventListener("keyup", checkKeyReleased);
var key = [];

function checkKeyPressed(e) {
  key[e.keyCode] = true;
}

function checkKeyReleased(e) {
  key[e.keyCode] = false;
}

function moveLeft() {
  var pos = document.getElementById("box").style.left;
  document.getElementById("box").style.left = parseInt(pos) - 5 + "px";
}

function moveUp() {
  var pos = document.getElementById("box").style.top;
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = parseInt(pos) - 5 + "px";
}

function moveRight() {
  var pos = document.getElementById("box").style.left;
  document.getElementById("box").style.left = parseInt(pos) + 5 + "px";
}

function moveDown() {
  var pos = document.getElementById("box").style.top;
  document.getElementById("box").style.top = parseInt(pos) + 5 + "px";
}

function move() {
  var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.top);
  var l = parseInt(document.getElementById("box").style.left);
  if (key[37] && l !== 0) {
    moveLeft();
  }
  if (key[38] && t !== 0) {
    moveUp();
  }
  if (key[39] && l !== 400) {
    moveRight();
  }
  if (key[40] && t !== 400) {
    moveDown();
  }
}
var timer = setInterval(move, 1);
```

```css
#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: orange;
}
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="box" style="top: 0; left: 0;"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a better suitable value like `10` for the delay. `1` is too small, and intervalled calls are cumulating.

Comment: Call `move` inside checkKeyPressed fn

Comment: Doesnt work, starts misbehaving. @MedetTleukabiluly